# Set representation allowing duplicates

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

From [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html):

> Exercise 2.60.  We specified that a
>   set would be represented as a list
>   with no duplicates. Now suppose we
>   allow duplicates. For instance, the
>   set {1,2,3} could be represented as
>   the list (2 3 2 1 3 2 2). Design
>   procedures element-of-set?,
>   adjoin-set, union-set, and
>   intersection-set that operate on this
>   representation. How does the
>   efficiency of each compare with the
>   corresponding procedure for the
>   non-duplicate representation? Are
>   there applications for which you would
>   use this representation in preference
>   to the non-duplicate one?

I wrote the following solution (some parts came from the book):

```
(define (element-of-set? x set)
  (cond ((null? set) false)
        ((equal? x (car set)) true)
        (else (element-of-set? x (cdr set)))))

(define adjoin-set cons)

(define (intersection-set set1 set2)
  (cond ((or (null? set1) (null? set2)) '())
        ((element-of-set? (car set1) set2)        
         (cons (car set1)
               (intersection-set (cdr set1) set2)))
        (else (intersection-set (cdr set1) set2))))

(define (union-set set1 set2)
  (cond ((null? set1) set2)
        ((null? set2) set1)
        (else (cons (car set1) (union-set (cdr set1) set2)))))1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as `adjoin-set` simply became `cons`, `union-set` can be defined as:

```
(define union-set append)
```